# Table of Integrals Question

Tags: calculus

Use a table of integrals to evaluate $\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{x^2 \sqrt{3+5x^2}}dx$ for $x>0$.

The book suggests using $\displaystyle \int{\frac{du}{u^2 \sqrt{a^2+u^2}}}=-\frac{\sqrt{a^2+u^2}}{a^2 u}+C$

This makes sense to me and they go on to elaborate that $a^2=3, u^2=5x^2, u=\sqrt{5}x, du=\sqrt{5}dx$.

They then suggest to multiply the numerator and denominator by $5$ so that we get the $u^2$ in the radical to match with the $u^2$ outside of the radical and this also makes sense. In other words,

$\displaystyle5\int\frac{1}{5x^2 \sqrt{3+5x^2}}dx$. From here, they somehow make the conclusion that the integral would look like this:

$\displaystyle 5 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\int\frac{1}{5x^2 \sqrt{3+5x^2}}\sqrt{5}dx$

Now this is where I start to get confused. From my understanding, I am replacing $du$ with $\sqrt{5} dx$ and that is fine, but then there is also a $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ outside the integral.

Furthermore they then jump to the conclusion that we would get $\displaystyle\sqrt{5}\cdot -\frac{\sqrt{3+5x^2}}{3\cdot \sqrt{5}x}+C=-\frac{\sqrt{3+5x^2}}{3x}+C$

and I am sitting here trying to understand where the $5$ that was outside the integral went.

So my two questions are, what happened to the $5$ outside of the integral and why do I also have a $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ which also seems to disappear?

Comment: $5\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt 5} = \sqrt 5$

Comment: Right but there is also the $\sqrt{5}$ in the integral. Why do I have both a $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ and a $\sqrt{5}$?

Comment: So that the integrand doesn't change, since $\sqrt 5 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt 5} = 1$. Note that  if you only have $\sqrt 5 \,dx$ the value would change. So you have to multiply by $\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}$ also.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. I guess for some reason I thought that if $du=\sqrt{5}dx$, I didn't need to account for the $\sqrt{5}$ whereas with the $5$, I just randomly included it so it made sense to divide by $5$ too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by going into the $u$-world rather than confusing it all. We have, after our substitution $u=\sqrt{5}x$:

$$I=5\int\dfrac{1}{u^2\sqrt{3+u^2}}\cdot\dfrac{\textrm du}{\sqrt{5}}$$
Or using the formula,

$$I=\dfrac{5}{\sqrt{5}}\cdot\left(-\dfrac{\sqrt{3+5x^2}}{3\sqrt{5}x}\right)+C$$

(I also substituted $u$ back.)

Now, notice that:
$$I=\dfrac{5}{\sqrt{5}\cdot\sqrt{5}}\cdot\left(-\dfrac{\sqrt{3+5x^2}}{3x}\right)+C$$

If you didn't realize already, the first fraction simply becomes $1$, and thus the final answer is obtained.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)